# Android browsers blocking Youtube preroll ads natively

Tags: chrome-for-android, youtube, firefox-for-android

I was wondering if anyone else noticed that Youtube preroll ads are automatically blocked when browsing on Android Chrome or Android Firefox. This is **without** any adblocking features enabled (no Adblock Plus installed, no Adblock installed in Firefox, no Firefox tracking protection enabled, etc.). I'm not complaining by any means, because I do everything I can to block ads, but I was wondering if anyone knew why this happens (I'm curious from a technical/networking standpoint).

Comment: I guess you can't simply add ads to a `<video>` tag for mobile users; media players will try to play a file as they can't handle chunked streams (as in YouTube's HTML5 player).

Comment: Can you clarify and explain a little more?  I don't understand.

Comment: Imagine you want to display ads, but the media player (stock one, no special features) only supports playing plain video files. Now you have no chance to add any (skippable) pre-rolls, mid-rolls or small banners. It's literally impossible to rerender a video for *every* user to fit ads for that single view. Thus YouTube simply doesn't implement a way to gain *minimal* revenue from a small amount of views (most of the views come from TVs/Smartphone apps that feature usual ads).

Comment: So when a video is played in Chrome Android or Firefox Android, you're saying it's actually using a media player?  Because the videos I'm talking about are being played within the browser.  But maybe they're using a media player.  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, they are using an *inline* media player. And that one is not able to display pre-/mid-rolls or banners.